# How can I send images and "key" "value" data in Okhttp?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-asynctask, okhttp

In my code application I wrote a method that sends a key and a value with `FormBody.Builder`, but I need to send an image too. How can I do that?

I wrote this

```
_formBuilder.add("id_user","1");
_formBuilder.add("name","David");
```

And then I send that value in a `Constructor` of an `AsyncTask` that receives the parameters:

```
try {
    Request _rbuilder = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .post(_parameters)
                        .build();
    Response _res= _client.newCall(_rbuilder).execute();
    return _res.body().string();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.i("Error task", ex.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `multipart/form-data` for upload to your server. First, create `MultipartBody` using `MultipartBody.Builder`

```
MultipartBody.Builder multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
multipartBodyBuilder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("key", "value");
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("image/png"); // or "image/jpeg" or any mime type you want
multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart(
        "fileKey",
        "fileName",
        RequestBody.create(mediaType, yourFile)
);
```

Then use it as post data in your request

```
Request _rbuilder = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .addHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    )
    .post(multipartBodyBuilder.build())
    .build();
```